# In R, how do I create a function where all the numbers in a vector are rescaled, Inf becomes 1, and -Inf becomes 0?

Tags: r, function, statistics

I'm a beginner in R and have an assignment where I have to create a function where all the numbers are rescaled, Inf is mapped to 1, and -Inf is mapped to 0. I understand how to do the rescale, I just don't know how to add to the function so Inf becomes 1 and -Inf becomes 0. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction or let me know what kind of commands in R will allow me to do that, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
rescale01<-function(x){  
   rng<-range(x, na.rm=TRUE, finite=TRUE)
    (x-rng[1])/(rng[2]-rng[1])
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just realized I made a typo in the earlier version. I want -Inf to be mapped to 0 and Inf to be mapped to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `atan`

```
f <- function(x) 0.5+atan(x)/pi
```

Comment: Almost: *"Inf is mapped to 1, and -Inf is mapped to -1"*, your function reverses the limits and goes from 0 to 1. `2*atan(x)/pi` is the right function. Upvote, but change it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the reminder! I made a typo there but not it is fixed.